# Mapping multidimensional array in rails to an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, multidimensional-array

I have a list of beers that a user has in their cellar through `cellared_beers` so that a user has many `beers` through `cellared_beers` and vice versa.  Each `cellared_beer` has extra data like year and size attached.

I am wanting to display the tallied results of the cellared_beers for a user on a page.  Right now I have the following code which will get the counts:

```
beer_groups = @user.cellared_beers.count(:group => [:beer_id,:year,:size])
=> {[1, 2008, "12oz"]=>1, [1, 2009, "12oz"]=>3, [1, 2010, "12oz"]=>1}
```

How do I map it out so that I can show the beer attributes based on beer_id, the year, size, and amount?

Something like:

```
Foo Beer(beer.name), Bar Brewery(beer.brewery.name),2008,12oz,1
Foo Beer(beer.name), Bar Brewery(beer.brewery.name),2009,12oz,3
Foo Beer(beer.name), Bar Brewery(beer.brewery.name),2010,12oz,1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean in a string, like this?

```
{[1, 2008, "12oz"]=>1, [1, 2009, "12oz"]=>3, [1, 2010, "12oz"]=>1}.each.map do |values,count| 
    beer = Beer.find(values[0])
   "#{beer.name}, #{beer.brewery.name},#{values[1]},#{values[2]}, #{count}"
end
```

Comment: @prognar thanks, edited to reflect your changes. It is not needed in ruby 1.9

Comment: Very close, but I had to add '.each' before '.map' since it was only returning the first set.  

I put it into an array beer_counts so it looks like:  
    `beer_counts = beer_groups.each.map do |values,count|
      beer = Beer.find(values[0])
      "#{beer.name},#{beer.brewery.name},#{beer.style},#{beer.abv},#{values[1]},#{values[2]}, #{count}"
    end`  

How will my view be able to go through each one?

Comment: Now you have an simple array of strings, so a `beer_counts.each` will work.